# VLC - scroll wheel doesn't change volume level

Tags: sound

I'm having trouble with vlc, when i try and adjust the volume with my scroll wheel it doesn't change the volume, in settings x-axis control is set to volume control so i can't understand why it wont work

Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: In what settings did you set the x-axis control? and does scrolling work in other programs eg. OpenOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 1.1.2 version of VLC and it does work. Give it a try. :)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me! Ctrl+H also would not turn VLC into minimal view as it should.

I was using the VLC in the Ubuntu repository, so I uninstalled that. 
Then I added the [Getdeb.net repository](http://www.getdeb.net/welcome/) (this is where VLC puts all of the new releases) and installed it from there and now it works perfect.

I don't know if this will work for you but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work i believe ctrl + up/down arrows will increase and decrease the volume as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VLC 2.0.1, I'm not sure but I think it might be available now in the 12.04 Software Center. For me it has not had any sound issues with the scroll wheel.

However, if you need the PPA that is directly from VideoLAN (VLC) then use these commands in your terminal (ctrl + alt + t) to add the newest VLC to your repository:

`1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily,
2) sudo apt-get update,
3) sudo apt-get install vlc`

Hope you get everything figured out and that everything works out for you.
Live long and prosper!

Comment: Oops, didn't realize this is a question from 2010.....my bad (palm2forhead)